# Regex for decimal number with optional decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

My requirement is to test the pasted data and if it fails then don't paste.

```
Regex: /\d{0,4}([\.|\,]\d{0,2})?/
```

Data used:

```
1.2 tests true
1.2.3 test true as well
```

Requirement is

min 0 max 4 digits before decimal point
decimal point can be either dot or comma
min 1 max 3 digits after decimal point if there exists a decimal point.

I have tried following but does not work.
Any help will be appreciated.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ue8gj52t/200/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From your requirements

```
/^\d{0,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,3})?$/
```

1. `^`: Start of the line
2. `\d{0,4}`: Zero-to-four digits
3. `[.,]`: Match dot or comma
4. `\d{1,3}`: One-to-three digits
5. `(?: ... )`: Non-capturing group
6. `(something)?` The group can occur zero or once
7. `$`: End of line

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d{0,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,3})?" />
```

Comment: Don't you have to escape the "." to prevent it from matching any character?

Comment: @grim No when used inside character group. Inside character group, it is treated as `.` literal.