# regex match value up to 2 decimal with point

Tags: regex

So I managed to get this REGEX working it matches up to 6 digits with decimal point, everything works as expected only problem is that is also accepting only the point at beginning which I don't want it needs to start with digit.

```
^(\d{1,6}|\d{0,6}\.)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$

1 -- match
11 -- match
111 -- match
1111 -- match
11111 -- match
111111 -- match
1. -- match (yes I want this to match like this)
1.00 -- match
11.01 -- match
111.10 -- match
1111.52 -- match
11111.23 -- match
111111.23 -- match
. -- match ... DONT want to match
```

Comment: `^(?!\.$)\d{0,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f7ruWn/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it matches .33 which mine does not

Comment: Ok, so `^(?=\d)\d{0,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`? Or just `^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`?

Comment: ^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$ this one seems to do the job, thanks, if u could put in answer i can accept it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for decimal number with optional decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387697/regex-for-decimal-number-with-optional-decimal-point)

Comment: This does not answer *this* question.

Comment: yes @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi it does not answer my question, and I,m guessing u down voted my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f7ruWn/4).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{1,6}` - one to six digits
- `(?:\.\d{0,2})?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and then zero, one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.